# R: plotting signals on the time series chart

Tags: r

I have a time series data set containing:

```
   Date Value Signal
1 1/1/16 0.56  A
2 1/2/16 0.70
3 1/3/16 0.12  B
4 1/4/16 0.33  C
5 1/5/16 0.35
```

I would like to plot values vs. date chart and place signals (from signal column) on the chart next to the values. What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to first plot the `Date` and `Value` columns in the initial [`plot()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/plot.html) call, and then make a subsequent call to [`text()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/text.html) to draw the `Signal` labels. We can compute an offset from the exact data points by calling `par('usr')` to get the user coordinate range of the plot (which was created dynamically during the `plot()` call), extract the y range, take the difference, and multiply it by a fraction, thereby defining the offset as a fraction of the y-coordinate range of the plot. The offset can alternatively (or additionally) be computed from the x-coordinate range for a horizontal offset, if you prefer.

This demo offsets the labels by 6% of the y-coordinate range:

```
## coerce Date column to Date type
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date,'%d/%m/%y');

## plot and label
plot(df$Date,df$Value,type='b');
text(df$Date,df$Value+diff(par('usr')[3:4])*6/100,df$Signal,xpd=NA);
```

**Data**

```
df <- data.frame(Date=c('1/1/16','1/2/16','1/3/16','1/4/16','1/5/16'),Value=c(0.56,0.7,0.12,
0.33,0.35),Signal=factor(c('A',NA,'B','C',NA)),stringsAsFactors=F);
```

[image: plot]

Comment: thank you! is there anyway to do this via  dygraph ? im working with always changing timeseries data so it makes using plot() a bit tricky.

Comment: @user3481603 I've never used that library, so couldn't say.